# Wordpress user account activation

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to implement user account activation in Wordpress, it's not a multi-site.

Once user registered through site or admin panel, user should get an email with activation link.

Once the link opened the account should get activated and should be redirected to login page. Also need to check the account is activated or not in login page.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called "User Activation Email” for non multi-site installations that seems to do the job you require: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-activation-email/